# Course framework using HTML and Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, frameworks

I am developing e-learning course framework Which will help me to develop course by just changing existing text and by just changing some resources(images,video,flash or audio) in my existing course. And my also thinking to add Export button which will export my course in some zip file.

So could I do this using Jquery and HTML

Please suggest me some tips.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that even without using jQuery, just with HTML. If you want it to be more manageable than editing HTML you should go for server side programming in PHP/RoR/ASP.NET/or anything else. If you want it to look better and have much more usable elements so users will do tasks in your application quickly then you could add CSS and Javascript ( this is where jQuery comes into play)...